# What is the smoothest way to scroll through a rich media webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I am making a webpage contains several JavaScript slideshows,loads of CSS, animated menu,and CSS transition animations,also my page height is very long on iPad. I have a navigation menu when user click it it will scroll to a specific location on the page using :

```
var $viewport = $('html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)');
    $viewport.animate({scrollTop: dest}, 2000, function(){menu_scrolling=false;});
```

My webpage can scrolling smooth like silk on my macbook pro,tested on Firefox, Chrome and safari but on my iPad, it is stuttering like hell, it's almost like skipped the animations, even the pinch zooming is laggy. 
I tried the jQuery scrollto plugin, jquery-animation enhanced plugin, those are all laggy on iPad.
What is the best way to make a menu to scroll through a rich media webpage smoothly on iPad?

Comment: so there is too much going on and it's struggling. have you tried 1) only animating what's actually visible and 2) pausing everything as soon as a scroll event is triggered and starting again as it stops?

Comment: Perhaps useful: [Visually Re-engineering CSS For Faster Paint Times](http://addyosmani.com/blog/devtools-visually-re-engineering-css-for-faster-paint-times/)

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be to rely on CSS transitions, and hopefully trigger hardware acceleration.

Say you apply

```
transition: all ease 0.5s;
```

to your container, then do something like

```
$container.css( 'transform', 'translate3d(0,' + offsetValue + 'px,0)' );
```

Once done, you can remove the transform and set the scrollTop to the right value so that the user can still manually scroll up and down the page.
To trigger hardware acceleration on iOS6 you might want to give this a quick look http://indiegamr.com/ios6-html-hardware-acceleration-changes-and-how-to-fix-them/